# Unable to send multiple associative array values from javascript/ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

We are trying to send multiple associative array values from javascript/ajax to php but we receive an empty object/array at the php file.

So can you please help to get values of an associative array from javascript to php?

1. We have tried serializing array and passing to a php file.
2. We have tried to convert an array to string and then try to pass it to a php file.

Please check the following code:

```
// javscript


function saveData(id) {


    //var actionData = [];
        var actionData = $('#' + id).closest('tr').find("[id^='action_']");
    var ownerData = $('#' + id).closest('tr').find("[id^='owner_']");
    //var type = $.type(actionData);
    //alert(type); exit();

    /*alert(actionData[0]['action']);exit;
    actionData['owner'] = $('#' + id).closest('tr').find("[id^='owner_']");
    actionData[2]['dueDate'] = $('#' + id).closest('tr').find("[id^='dueDate_']");
    actionData[3]['completedDate'] = $('#' + id).closest('tr').find("[id^='completedDate_']");

    //var myData = JSON.stringify(actionData['owner']);

    //alert($('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#projId').val());*/
    var dataObject = [];
    dataObject['projId'] = $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#projId').val();

    //alert(myData);
  //var newData1 = $.extend({}, actionData['owner']);
  var newData = $.extend({}, dataObject);

        /*dataObject = {
            projId:                  $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#projId').val(),
            riskNumber:              $('#' + id).closest('tr').children('td#riskNumber').text().slice(0,-4),
            cause:                   $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#cause').val(),
            effect:                  $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#effect').val(),
            functionAffectedControl: $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#functionAffectedControl :selected').val(),
            categoryControl:         $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#categoryControl :selected').val(),
            impact:                  $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#impact :selected').val(),
            severityControls:        $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#severityControls').val(),
            probability:             $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#probability :selected').val(),
            riskOwnerControl:        $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#riskOwnerControl :selected').val(),
            manageability:           $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#manageability :selected').val(),
            residualProbability:     $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#residualProbability :selected').val(),
            residualImpact:          $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#residualImpact :selected').val(),
            statusControl:           $('#' + id).closest('tr').find('#statusControl :selected').val()
            //actions:                 JSON.stringify(actionArray)
            //owners:                  $('#' + id).closest('tr').find("[id^='owner_']").val(),
            //dueDates:                $('#' + id).closest('tr').find("[id^='dueDate_']"),
            //CompletedDates:          $('#' + id).closest('tr').find("[id^='completedDate_']")

        }*/


    $.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "/apps/projmgmt/reports/SaveData.php",
        data:   { data: actionData, owner:ownerData}, //
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('Data Saved Successfully');

        }
    });

}

// html

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped tree-basic">
                <tbody>
                {foreach from=$obj->getRiskActionList() name=risk item=risk}
                <tr class="{$class}" data-count="2" id="{$k}">
                    {$i = $i+1}
                    {$class='treegrid-'|cat:$i}
                    {$j = $i-1}
                    {$classNode='treegrid-parent-'|cat:$j}
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;">
                        <div class="treegrid-container">
                            <span class="treegrid-expander treegrid-expander-collapsed"></span>
                            {'ACTION'|gettext|escape}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="6" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="actionId[]" id="actionId_{$k}" value="{$risk->getId()|escape}" />
                        <div class="treegrid-container">
                            <span class="treegrid-expander"></span>
                            <textarea rows="2" cols="100" id="action_{$k}" name="mitigationAction[]" maxlength="256">{$risk->getMitigationAction()|escape}</textarea></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="{$class} {$classNode}">
                    {$i = $i+1}
                    {$class='treegrid-'|cat:$i}
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;" >
                        <div class="treegrid-container">
                            <span class="treegrid-expander"></span>{'OWNER_NAME'|gettext|escape}</div></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="actionOwner[]" size="50"  id="owner_{$k}" value="{$risk->getOwnerName()|escape}" maxlength="80"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" >{'DUE_DATE'|gettext|escape}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" class="riskPopupCalendar" id="actionDueDate_{$i}" name="actionDueDate[]" value="{$smarty.request.actionDueDate[$i]|escape}">
                        <div size="10" name="actionDueDateText[]" id="dueDate_{$k}">{if null != {$risk->getDueDate()|escape}}{$risk->getDueDate()->format('d/m/Y')|escape}{/if}</div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="/images/calendar.gif" id="actionDueDateDatepicker_{$i}" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" class="riskPopupCalendarDelete" style="width:16px;height:16px;"
                                                         data-input="actionDueDate_{$i}" data-text="actionDueDateText_{$i}" id="actionDueDateDelete_{$i}"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" >{'COMPLETED_DATE'|gettext|escape}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" class="riskPopupCalendar" id="actionCompletedDate_{$i}" name="actionCompletedDate[]" value="{$smarty.request.actionCompletedDate[$i]|escape}">
                        <div size="10" name="actionCompletedDateText[]" id="completedDate_{$k}>{if null != {$risk->getCompletedDate()|escape}}{$risk->getCompletedDate()->format('d/m/Y')|escape}{/if}</div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="/images/calendar.gif" id="actionCompletedDateDatepicker_{$i}" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="/images/calendar_delete.gif" class="riskPopupCalendarDelete" style="width:16px;height:16px;"
                                                         data-input="actionCompletedDate_{$i}" data-text="actionCompletedDateText_{$i}" id="actionCompletedDateDelete_{$i}"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="{$class} {$classNode}">
                    <div class="treegrid-container">
                        <span class="treegrid-expander"></span>
                        <td data-column="name"><img src="/images/blank.gif" class="ib_left"><input type="button" id="{$k|escape}" name="removeActionButton" value="{'REMOVE_ACTION'|gettext|escape}" class="removeActionButton ib"><img src="/images/blank.gif" class="ib_right"></td></div>
                </tr>
                    {$i = $i+1}
                    {$k = $k+1}
                    {$class='treegrid-'|cat:$i}
                {/foreach}
                <tr>
                    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                    <td align="right"><img src="/images/blank.gif" class="ib_left"><input type="button" onclick="updateData('{$row}','{$k}');"  data-number="{$i}" value="{'ADD_ACTION'|gettext|escape}" class="addActionButton ib"><img src="/images/blank.gif" class="ib_right"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you data is what you think it is:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ data: actionData, owner:ownerData})
console.log(data)
```

If it is then sent the data object in your ajax call. Then on the the php side I would confirm that the received data matches the sent data. Then parse said data. This should help you narrow down and resolve your issue(s).